# Javafx stage.close() and stage.hide() didn't work

Tags: javafx, hide, fxml

```
 Stage myStage = new Stage();
 Scene scene;    
 public void switchScene() throws IOException {
    URL location = getClass().getResource("../View/character.fxml");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(location);
    scene = new Scene(loader.load(location.openStream()), 900, 650);
    myStage.setScene(scene);
    myStage.setTitle("Character Setting");
    myStage.show();
}

public void exit(){
    myStage.close();
}
```

I want to close myStage but when I run the exit method, nothing happen. (I use a Controller class to trigger a Button to execute the exit method)

FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="exit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exit" text="Exit" />
```

Comment: Please show where you are calling the `switchScene()` and `exit()` methods from.

Comment: I call it from another fxml, but they have same Controller class.`<Button fx:id="myButton2" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#switchScene" text="Character Settings" />`

Comment: But if they are different fxml files, they will be different controller instances.

Comment: Oh, I just start to learn javafx :D It make sense now. Thanks